# Ошибка подключения через mysql-connector-python (Access denied for user (using password: NO))

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, mysqlconnector

Подключаюсь к удаленной MariaDB базе, использую следующий код:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT, user=USER, password=PASSWORD, charset=CHARSET, auth_plugin=AUTH_PLUGIN)
```

В переменной AUTH_PLUGIN хранится "caching_sha2_password" (без этого получаю ошибку 2003 Authentication with backend failed). При попытке запуска кода получаю ошибку:

```
Access denied for user 'username'@'host' (using password: NO)
```

Почему-то происходит подключение без пароля, хотя я его явно передаю в connect. Подскажите, чем может быть дело?

UPDATE:
Обнаружил, что при auth_plugin=mysql_clear_password ошибка меняется на "Access denied for user 'username'@'host' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Вы не правильно указали аргумент `password` попробуйте поменять на `passw`

Comment: @ІванШнір В таком случае получаю "Unsupported argument passw". Обнаружил, что при auth_plugin=mysql_clear_password логин все так же не проходит, но при этом в ошибке теперь (using password: YES). Добавлю в вопрос